# Looking for an XMPP server library written in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xmpp

I am in the process of building a web based chat app written in Ruby. I would like to provide the ability to also connect to this chat server using an XMPP client. So I am looking for a library that will handle being a real XMPP server which I can tie into with my existing Ruby code (or by using something like Redis in between). However, I am having a hard time finding the server library (though I can find many libraries for acting as a client which consumes or interacts with the server). I'm also not very experienced with XMPP to begin with so I may be asking for the wrong thing. Do you know of an XMPP server library I can use?

Answer (score 5):

XMPP server libraries generally don't make much sense, as XMPP servers (like HTTP servers for example) run as separate standalone long-lived processes. You don't usually embed them into your application.

XMPP is even a step further from HTTP - there *are* HTTP server libraries that allow you to listen on a port, wait for requests, and send a response. XMPP is completely different in this aspect - XMPP sessions are long-lived, and require constant attention. Using an XMPP server library your application would spend most of the time inside that library - at which point, why isn't it as good as running a separate process?

I know it's a tempting idea, but having developed an XMPP server and thinking about this (people have requested it before you) I just concluded it made very little sense (even if it is *technically* possible).

Many XMPP servers allow custom plugins for integration with other systems, and there are servers in Ruby if that's a requirement for you (e.g. [Vines](http://www.getvines.org/)).

Comment: I think you have explained it more eloquently than I did. I want to run a standalone XMPP server (not embed one in my app) and add customizations/extensions to the XMPP server in order to pass messages between the two. Vines looks close to what I am trying to do, so I will check it out.

Answer (score 4):

Try [XMPP4R](https://github.com/ln/xmpp4r)

For example - connection and authentication:

```
require "xmpp4r"

robot = Jabber::Client::new(Jabber::JID::new("sample@xmpp.ru"))
robot.connect
robot.auth("password")
```

And sending message:

```
message = Jabber::Message::new("recipient@xmpp.ru", "Hi there!")
message.set_type(:chat)

robot.send message
```

But the library is somewhat unstable under Windows, but great in Linux.

There is also XMPP server implementation under Ruby using XMPP4R - http://code.google.com/p/xmpp-rserve/

**EDIT**

Maybe this is what you want. Looks like a library suitable for server usage - https://github.com/sprsquish/blather

Found it on XMPP official page - http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I am not trying to connect to an existing server as a bot. I am trying to BE the server. But maybe I misunderstood your answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, I used XMPP4R only for client-side. But as I suspect it is suitible not only for client-side. It is often stated if the library only client-side or not. Also, the last link points out to Ruby xmpp server implementation using XMPP4R. But it seems that project is in very early stage. There is notning useful in the repo right now. You could try to contact with the author by mail.